# Add text with jQuery (fakeloader.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loader, preloader

Hi guys i'm trying to add text to the loading screen of fakeLoader.js

here is the script but i dont know how to add text for example

this is the code working:

```
$(".box-loader-screen").fakeLoader({
        timeToHide:5200,
        bgColor:"#3AA9D7",
        spinner:"spinner5",
        zIndex: "99999"
    });
```

but i want to add text into the config into the script

"Please wait..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script doesn't allow to put text, but you can create an image (a cool animated GIF, maybe) and put the text on it.

```
$(".box-loader-screen").fakeLoader({
    imagePath:"yourPath/customizedImage.gif";
});
```

Or, you can edit the script (and create a "text" option.
The easy way: search the line 82 https://github.com/joaopereirawd/fakeLoader.js/blob/master/fakeLoader.js#L82 :

```
if (settings.imagePath !='') {
    el.html('<div class="fl"><img src="'+settings.imagePath+'"></div>');
    centerLoader();
}
// add this
else {
    el.html('<div class="fl">Your content here</div>');
}
```

And add your own CSS styles.